# ADT 16.0.1 with Eclipse Indigo on Fedora 16 is not working

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I installed ADT 16.0.1 in eclipse indigo on fedora 16 successfully. But after installing that I do not find Android option in preferences from where I can set the location of android sdk. So why eclipse doesn't show the option of Android in preferences even after successful installation of ADT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Fedora 16 and eclipse Indigo 3.7.1. I had to remove the ADT plug-in from Eclipse. Then open a terminal and login as root. then run eclipse from terminal and reinstall plug-in. I changed the workspace from root to the default home/yourname/workspace. then close eclipse- log out of terminal. then re-open eclipse from desktop. Your android stuff should be there.I also installed Linux-tools( in eclipse- logged in as root)- hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) is complete guide to setup Android build Enviornment.
 Read the Step3 there properly, it should work. Also never install eclipse from Software manager or command prompt, instead download it from eclipse website

Comment: I have already read that. Problem is different. Just read the question again.

Comment: which eclipse version you have installed ? For Android development ubuntu is preferred Linux OS, although you can use any. Just to make sure your adt is installed properly, check for updates and see whether it goes to check for ADT also or not.

Comment: I have already mentioned in question that I am using eclipse indigo. Checking for update is not the solution, because if something is installed already why eclipse is not able to recognize it?